# How to modify a record within a record type in oracle forms

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

I created 3 blocks in my oracle 10g form, Headers, Lines and Lines Details. I am fetching the records using cursors for all the three blocks everything is working fine. Now in Lines Details block there is a numeric field called priority. By default I am using FIFO method for priority value starting from 1 to n numbers. Now I want user to decide the priority such that any specific record can be shifted up or down to increase or decrease the priority without committing line details. Once user is satisfied with priority he will click on save to commit the changes. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the changed record and based on the current priority value make it current priority +/- number of times user clicked Up or Down. Declare a record type variable with exact number of columns as in your lines details data block.  Copy the all records including the changed record into record type variable. Clear block with no validate and then re-populate the changed record. To shift the record as per the priority values modify your default order by clause. This will solve your problem.